# ArgoCD: How to not store semi-secret information in manifests?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, argocd

I'm learning K8s, so bear with me as a noob.

I'm running a single-node K3s cluster at home, and have successfully deployed the [traefik/whoami](https://hub.docker.com/r/traefik/whoami) application using the command below, but would like to deploy it via ArgoCD.

```
cat apps/whoami/whoami.yaml | envsubst | kubectl apply -f -
```

The manifest I created.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: k3s-test
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: whoami-deploy
  namespace: k3s-test
  labels:
    app: whoami
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: traefik/whoami:v1.8.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami-svc
  namespace: k3s-test
  labels:
    service: whoami
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: whoami
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami-ingress
  namespace: k3s-test
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
spec:
  rules:
    - host: whoami.${DOMAIN_NAME}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: whoami-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I want to publish my code to GitHub so that ArgoCD can sync it, but don't want to expose information that is not necessarily secret, but not necessarily public. Currently, my domain name is set as an environment variable (because I don't want to commit mydomain.com to my GitHub repo) and I'm using `envsubst` when running `kubectl apply`. Does ArgoCD have similar functionality? I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/5580) showing ArgoCD probably doesn't have variable interpolation, but is there an alternative? Or do I need to store my domain name as a full-on K8s secret?

Comment: Have you considered using a private Github repository? ArgoCD accepts credentials for git repos: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/private-repositories/

Comment: I did. I would prefer not to do this, but it's an option.

Comment: you can make a custom plugin to run your `envsubst` before generating the manifest https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/config-management-plugins/#option-1-configure-plugins-via-argo-cd-configmap